core dumped error while inserting into avl tree
I have this AVL search tree template class, which in main function as I call insert public method I get the error. I call the method inside main
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
#ifndef _TREE_H
#define _TREE_H
 
struct DocumentItem {
    string documentName;
    int count;
    DocumentItem(string& docName,int& c) : documentName(docName),count(c)
    {}
};
 
struct WordItem {
    string word;
    vector<DocumentItem> documents;
    WordItem(string w, string docName,int &c )
    {
        word = w;
        DocumentItem doc(docName,c);
        documents.push_back(doc);
    }
};
template <class Key, class Value>
    class AVLSearchTree
    {
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            Node* left;
            Node* right;
            int height;
            Key key;
            Value value;
            Node(const Key&k, const Value& v)
                : key(k), value(v), height(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
        };
       
        Node* root;
       
        int height(Node* t) const
        {
            if (t == NULL) { return -1; }
            return t->height;
        }
       
        void rotateWithRightChild(Node*& k1) const
        {
            Node* k2 = k1->right;
            k1->right = k2->left;
            k2->left = k1;
            k1->height = max(height(k1->left), height(k1->right)) + 1;
            k2->height = max(height(k2->right), k1->height) + 1;
            k1 = k2;
        }
        
        void rotateWithLeftChild(Node * & k2 ) const
        {
        Node *k1 = k2->left;
        k2->left = k1->right;
        k1->right = k2;
        k2->height = max( height( k2->left ), height( k2->right ) ) + 1;
        k1->height = max( height( k1->left ), k2->height ) + 1;
        k2 = k1;
        }
       
        void doubleWithLeftChild(Node*& k3) const
        {
            rotateWithRightChild(k3->left);
            rotateWithLeftChild(k3);
        }
       
        void doubleWithRightChild(Node*& k1) const
        {
            rotateWithLeftChild(k1->right);
            rotateWithRightChild(k1);
        }
       
        void insert(Node*& t, const Key& k, const Value& v)
        {
            if (t == NULL)
            {
                t = new Node(k, v);
            }
            else if (k < t->key)
            {
                // Inserted into left tree
                insert(t->left, k, v);
                if (height(t->left) - height(t->right) == 2)
                {
                    if (k < t->left->key) // k was inserted to the left-left subtree
                        rotateWithLeftChild(t);
                    else
                        doubleWithLeftChild(t);
                }
            }
            else if (k > t->key)
            {
                // Inserted into right tree
                insert(t->right, k, v);
                if (height(t->right) - height(t->left) == 2)
                {
                    if (k > t->right->key)
                        rotateWithRightChild(t);// k was inserted to the right-right subtree
                    else
                        doubleWithRightChild(t);
                }
            }
            //update the height of the node
            t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right)) + 1;
        }
       
        int max(int lhs, int rhs) const
        {
            if (lhs > rhs)
            return lhs;
            return rhs;
        }
       
        int getBalance(Node* node) const {
            return (node == NULL) ? 0 : height(node->left) - height(node->right);
        }
       
        void remove(const Key x, Node*& t) const
        {
            if (t == NULL)
                return; // Item not found; do nothing
            if (x < t->key)
                remove(x, t->left);
            else if (t->key < x)
                remove(x, t->right);
            else if (t->left != NULL && t->right != NULL) // Two children
            {
                t->key = findMin(t->right)->key; // t is replaced with the right minimum's value
                remove(t->key, t->right); // right minimum is removed
            }
            else // one or no children
            {
                Node* oldNode = t;
                t = (t->left != NULL) ? t->left : t->right; // new replacement
                delete oldNode;
            }
           
            if (t != NULL) {
                t->height = 1 + std::max(height(t->left), height(t->right));
                int balance = getBalance(t);
                // Left Heavy
                if (balance > 1) {
                // Left-Left Case
                if (getBalance(t->left) >= 0)
                rotateWithLeftChild(t);
                // Left-Right Case
                else {
                doubleWithLeftChild(t);
                }
                }
                // Right Heavy
                else if (balance < -1) {
                // Right-Right Case
                if (getBalance(t->right) <= 0)
                rotateWithRightChild(t);
                // Right-Left Case
                else {
                doubleWithRightChild(t);
                }
                }
            }
        }
       
        Node* find(const Key& x, Node* t) const
        {
            if (t == NULL)
                return NULL;
            else if (x < t->key)
                return find(x, t->left);
            else if (t->key < x)
                return find(x, t->right);
            else
                return t; // Match
        }
        void makeEmpty(Node*& t) const
        {
            // Recursively deletes the tree
            if (t != NULL)
            {
            makeEmpty(t->left);
            makeEmpty(t->right);
            delete t->value; // deletes the value which is wordItem
            delete t;
            }
           
            t = NULL;
        }
 
       
    public:
        AVLSearchTree() : root(NULL) {}
        ~AVLSearchTree()
        {
            makeEmpty(root);
        }
       
        void insert(const Key& key, const Value& value)
        {
            insert(root, key, value);
        }
       
        void remove(const Key& x)
        {
            remove(x, root);
        }
       
        bool doesExist(Key& key)
        {
            if (find(key, root) == NULL)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
       
        Value& getWordItem(Key& key)
        {
            return find(key, root)->value;
        }
       
        const Key& findMin()
        {
            return findMin(root)->key;
        }
    };
#endif
 
 
int main()
{
    
    AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem *> myTree;
    
    string s = "someword";
    string filename = "a.txt";
    if(!myTree.doesExist(s))
    {
        int initToOne = 1;
        WordItem item(s, filename, initToOne);
    myTree.insert(s,  &item);

    }
    
    return 0;
}
 

The error I get is:
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)

Also I realize the only code that runs is

            if (t == NULL)
            {
                t = new Node(k, v);
            }


Since I insert into an empty tree.

The first thing to look for when you have a double free are classes that do not observe the rules of Three, Five, or Zero.

makeEmpty seems to be missing.

It doesn't matter here, but when using a member initializer list remember that the members will be initialized in the order they are defined in the class definition and NOT the order they are listed in the member initializer list.

I deleted makeEmpty to produce less noise in the question and the code.

Understood, but now we can't compile and test the program. Be careful when minimizing the example code to leave the problem intact. Right now we can't compile the program and thus cannot reach the error you're asking about. If you don't need something in the example, you have to also remove everything that depends on it and test the program to make sure it doesn't add new problems or change the problem you're asking about. When making an example, use [mre] for inspiration.

edited, noted now, much thanks @user4581301

Probably unrelated: Identifiers staring with an underscore can cause problems if you don't know the rules. _TREE_H probably isn't hurting the program, but when you break the rules and it does bite you, the results are extremely bizarre and can take days to figure out. Best to just not break them.

MakeEmpty is a problem, if not the problem: delete t->value; isn't necessarily a pointer and in this case wasn't dynamically allocated: WordItem item(s, filename, initToOne) You can't safely delete something if you don't know where it came from. The only thing in the program directly allocated with new and can be deleteed are the Nodes.

I see, so I might use new as I construct WordItem in my main. yet I don't even run remove or makeempty, so something else must be crashing I thought ? @user4581301

MakeEmpty is invoked by the AVLSearchTree destructor. It will run when the program exits. If I comment out delete t->value;, the program runs to completion: https://godbolt.org/z/zsnKzdrfj It may or may not do what you want it to do, but it no longer crashes. I like crashes. When a program crashes, you know you got something wrong.

wow, indeed as I used myTree.insert(s,  new WordItem(s, filename, initToOne)); it didn't crash. I will now do some print debugging. I didn't guess it would run delete at program exit. @user4581301

Recommendation: Don't use new unless you're forced to. It greatly complicates the management of the program. If you can  get rid of the pointer completely and use automatic allocation, not only is the code simpler (management is automatic), it's often faster because the CPU doesn't have to go chasing after pointers to find and load the data. The data was probably already loaded by the CPU along with the object that contains it. See if this works for you: https://godbolt.org/z/xEGGzdTz1

You tripped over Scope. When an automatically allocated object goes out of scope, the destructor runs. AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem *> myTree; is automatically allocated and will go out of scope at the end of main. It holds a bunch of dynamically allocated objects (and that's why you must implement at least the rule of three).

Automatic allocations are handled automatically when they pass out of scope. Dynamic allocations have dynamic scope and you have to manage those yourself (or use smart pointers-automatically allocated variables that look after a dynamic resource for you)) .

Useful reading: What is ownership of resources or pointers? and What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?

And now I've gone and spent an hour answering a question in the comments again.

@Tufan Why AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem *> instead of AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem>?  Have you tested your AVL tree on something like this, or something simple as AVLSearchTree<string, int>?  If it can't work for int, it isn't going to work for anything else/different.  You should be striving to make your template value-based, i.e. it handles T, not T*.  If the user of the class wants to use T*, then it's the user's responsiblity to manage the pointers involved.

At the end of main
AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem *> myTree;

goes out of scope and is destroyed. That will invoke
void makeEmpty(Node*& t) const
{
    // Recursively deletes the tree
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        makeEmpty(t->left);
        makeEmpty(t->right);
        delete t->value; // deletes the value which is wordItem
        delete t;
    }
    t = NULL;
}

Unfortunately, the only WordItem in the tree was automatically allocated
WordItem item(s, filename, initToOne);

and cannot be safely deleted.
One could dynamically allocate item with new so that it can be deleteed, but that increases the complexity of the program and probably slows it down as the CPU has to chase down the object at the pointer and load it when it could have been loaded along with the Node that references it. In general avoid new where possible.
The better option is to go with automatic allocation right at the beginning
int main()
{
    AVLSearchTree<string, WordItem> myTree; // no more pointer
    
    string s = "someword";
    string filename = "a.txt";
    if(!myTree.doesExist(s))
    {
        int initToOne = 1;
        WordItem item(s, filename, initToOne);
        myTree.insert(s,  item); // no more pointer
    }
    return 0;
}

Now that Node directly contains the WordItem, destroying the Node destroys WordItem and MakeEmpty only needs to worry about the Node
void makeEmpty(Node*& t) const
{
    // Recursively deletes the tree
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        makeEmpty(t->left);
        makeEmpty(t->right);
        delete t;
    }
    t = NULL;
}

